# Rails ajax with wicked_pdf

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, pdf

Rails 5
Нужно генерить .pdf из html странички. Использую 
gem '[wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)'
Сделал минимально рабочую версию

```
= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'
body onload="test()"
 #chartdiv

javascript:
    function test() {
      $('#chartdiv').html('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
    }
```

Контроллер (экшн исполняется при нажатии на кнопку):

```
def show
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json
        format.pdf do
          render pdf: 'poll_result',
                 javascript_delay: 2000,
                 template: 'admin/polls/show.html.slim',
                 layout: 'pdf.html.slim'
        end
      end
    end
```

Работает, но мне нужно отрисовывать данные которые прийдут с сервера через аякс
Как только додаю запрос, страничка pdf - белая

```
$.ajax({
            url: "https://httpbin.org/get",
            method: 'get',
        }).then(function (response) {
            $('#chartdiv').html('<h1>NEW Hello World</h1>');
        })
```

Перечитал как решать эту проблему, пробовал разные варианты, но не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В чем профит получать данные через ajax? Ведь пустая pdf не нужна. Почему просто не сделать серверный рендеринг? Нужны данные? Cделай запрос в контролере, получи данные, подставь в шаблон, проще не куда.

Comment: Согласен с этим человеком - @AfsmNGhr. У вас какая-то муть, чушь и компот выходит. Тем более столько времени прошло с момента создания вами вопроса...

Comment: Кажись вы не передали в ajax данные для преобразования

Comment: @AfsmNGhr Во первых никто не казал что пдф первоначально пустая. Будет отправлен аякс запрос на получения жсона, на основе которого плагин будет генерировать графики в формате svg

Comment: @Colibri А как связано время создания вопроса с ответом на него? Я находил похожую проблему, был ответ и он помог. Мне не помогает, может допустил мелкую ошибку.

Comment: @Ostap34PHP Это тестовый запрос, я ничего не хочу передавать и принимать, просто чтобы он был. Я думаю если этот простой вариант не работает, то другие не будут тем более